# Html5 video player customize to only show play and mute

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

i'm trying to add some controls to a HTML5 video player that is used by Layerslider wordpress plugin. You can add some custom HTML to each layer and you can also add javascript. But the mute button does not work :( Anything wrong with the code or does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work?? I also tried loading the javascript on the page seperatly.

Thanks in advance.

Related url:  http://www.welzendesign.com/startransfer/

```
    <video id="myVideo" width="50%" height="50%" autoplay loop>
        <source src="/startransfer/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/StarTransfer-promo-aanhanger.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <button class="mute-video">toggle</button>

        <style>

.mute-video {
            background:url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/64/60750.png) no-repeat center;
            background-size:32px;
            border:0;
            width:32px;
            height:32px;
            text-indent:-999px;
        }
        .unmute-video {
            background:url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/64/498.png) no-repeat center;
            background-size:32px;
        }
</style>

        <script>

 a"$("video").prop('unmuted', true);

        $(".mute-video").click(function () {
            if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
                $("video").prop('muted', false);
                $(this).addClass('unmute-video');

            } else {
                $("video").prop('muted', true);
                $(this).removeClass('unmute-video');
            }
            console.log($("video").prop('muted'))
        }); 

</script>
```

Comment: You have an error in your javascript. Check the console. I copy pasted your code in a fiddle, and it works perfectly: hhttp://jsfiddle.net/uyn4jfcr/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was the correct answer if anyone else has this problem:

```
function(element) {
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.mute-video', function (){
        if (jQuery("video").prop('muted')) {
            jQuery("video").prop('muted', false);
            jQuery(this).addClass('unmute-video');

        } else {
            jQuery("video").prop('muted', true);
            jQuery(this).removeClass('unmute-video');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `<script>` tag copy/paste this (your code, which is correct), delete all the alerts and extra `<script>` tags and it should work just fine.

```
        $("video").prop('unmuted', true);

        $(".mute-video").click(function() {
            if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
                $("video").prop('muted', false);
                $(this).addClass('unmute-video');

            } else {
                $("video").prop('muted', true);
                $(this).removeClass('unmute-video');
            }
            console.log($("video").prop('muted'))
        });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I still can't get it to work. I used your code snippet.

(index):180 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: Somewhere in the final `<script>`, the one with this snippet, you have a " a " " string that needs to be removed.

Comment: As I can see you don't have $ defined in your window. It was redefined as lsjQuery. So, the snippet cannot work. For starters try to replace & with lsjQuery, and hopefully this time it will work. The main issue it's not the way this snippet was written, it's the little bugs that the code has.